# Is it possible to connect arduino pro with an android phone with a usb cable?

Tags: arduino, usb, android, usb-host

I would like to read some potentiometers into my android phone. Is it possible to connect an arduino (ideally the arduino pro w/ USB-Serial-FTDI) to an android phone*? Other than the software part, I'm also wondering about the physical connection. I can't find a micro-b to micro-b usb cable on the internet.

[image: Android usb port placed next to Arudino pro USB port]

*I have an Android phone that runs version 4.x and another that runs 4.4.4.

Comment: Bluetooth may be a simpler solution here; especially when it comes to hard- and software support on the phone.

Comment: "I can't find a mini-b to mini-b usb cable on the internet." - That's because the USB standard prohibits this (and other) combinations, and, thus, there are hardly any use cases for it in the wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if the phone supports USB OTG. FTDI have [Android drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) on their website. It should be even possible to access it like a normal serial port, details are [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm)

The connector is not mini-b, this is micro-b (the board) and micro-ab (the phone). You need OTG cable with micro-a and micro-b such as [this](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/DISTRIBUTED-BY-MCM-HK-MUS14-/83-11872).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The phone doesn't look like micro-ab. It looks like micro-b to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/Pq5UmynpDs5GZuVlIqkPpf6IGEN9z2O2uYFkxRo3FXa-=w908-h464-no

Comment: Both pictured connectors are micro-b. If the phone really has OTG hardware, you have to use non-standard cable that has micro-b conector wired as a micro-a, such as [this one](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1099) together with second cable that has regular a(male) and micro-b.